# Чашка или кружка?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Речь конкретно о посуде вот такого типа (на них еще делают по заказу любые рисунки):

[image]

У нас (в Крыму, на Украине) их большей частью называют все-таки чашками, а в России — кружками. Но я считаю, что кружка — это литровая посудина для пива.
Кто прав?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На мой вкус чашка от кружки ничем принципиальным не отличается. Поэтому путаница объяснима. 
А если и отличается, то наличием блюдца, обычно входящего в комплект с чашкой. То, что на рисунке, я бы назвал кружкой. Это не противоречит версии о высоте сосуда. 
Что касается этимологии, то она интересна, но различий не поясняет, значения сильно изменились.

Интересно другое. Очень и очень от многих слышал, как кружки - именно такие - называют бокалами. Даже на ценниках видел неоднократно. Видимо, по той же самой логике, что кружка - это нечто массивное, для пива - в частности.

Comment: Мне казалось, что бокал не имеет ручки. Ножку - да, может иметь. Ручку - нет.

Answer (score 11):

Не могу говорить о диалектах, но как правило кружкой называют сосуд с ручкой, где высота больше, чем диаметр верхней части, а у чашки соотношение обратное. Правда из-за того, что чашки, как правило, имеют форму полусферы, и более тонкие, чем у кружки, стенки, то кружки с тонкими выпуклыми стенками тоже иногда называют чашками. В целом - если после отбития ручки получается стакан, то перед нами кружка, а если пиала - чашка.

На вашей фотографии изображена кружка.

Comment: В целом, соглашусь. Кружка - она обычно цилиндром. Чашка - полусферой. Как минимум габариты таковы, что чашки обычно меньше кружек. Соответственно, с чашки можно спокойно пить кофе (капуччино, эспрессо и пр.) - 1 порцию. А с кружки можно выхлебать литр пива или у меня, например, есть кружка для чая - что-то объемом в районе 300 мл.

Comment: Как по мне, из чашки пьют ЧАЙ (или кофе), а из кружки — квас или пиво.

Comment: @Fuchoin Kazuki, что из чего пьют это уже следствие, а не причина. Нескафе в рекламах предлагает пить её кофе из фирменной кружки ( такого же типа как и на картинке в вопросе). Просто горячие напитки из чашки пить удобнее, так как в ней быстрее остывает.

Comment: Ну, это традиция - пить чай и кофе из чашек с блюдцем, а не из кружек. В принципе, правильная. Чая и кофе много, наверное, не надо. Но я лично тот еще водохлеб :-)

Answer (score 4):

**ЧАШКА** - небольшой сосуд для питья округлой формы, обычно с ручкой, из фарфора, фаянса: кофейная чашка, пить чай из чашек.

**КРУЖКА** - сосуд в форме стакана с ручкой: пивная кружка, выпить кружку кваса.

Сейчас  много видов  кружек и чашек (толстые стенки\тонкие, цилиндрической формы\зауженные книзу и т. д.). Отличительная черта - высота. У Вас - кружка.

Answer (score 3):

Если обратиться к этимологии, кружка – от "кувшина", по одной версии: из польск. kruż «кувшин», связанного с ср.-в.-нем. krûse и далее — с греч. κρωσσός «кувшин». По другой версии - из др.-русск. крѹжькъ (ср.: русск. кружок), связано с круг: от старинного “кружало”, т. е. обносить по кругу в пиру; к сожалению, не описана форма сосуда, но на иллюстрациях древних пиров сосуд похож на кувшин, иногда говорили "кубок". Из «Толкового словаря живого великорусского языка» В. И. Даля: «Кружка — питейный сосуд больше стакана, кубок, стопа, братина, большой стакан, стакан с ручкою, иногда с носком и с крышечкою».

Чашка – от " чаша", кубок.Ча́шка (устар. — чаша; польск. czaszka — череп) — сосуд небольшого объёма (прибл. 200 мл), имеющий форму полусферы (с возможными вариациями), к которой опционально присоединена кольцевидная «ручка» для держания, сначала была на ножке и с 2 ручками, а без ручек на ножке - чарка, чара. Сосуд используется для непосредственного питья горячих напитков (чарка - для горячительных). В некоторых культурах из чашек принято также есть, в Японии распространена чашка без ручки — пиала.
Т. е. кружка высокая, чашка низкая.

Видимо, на Украине в значении "кубок" слова пересекаются, почему бы их и не поменять значениями, разница-то условна, если назначение стало одинаково.

Во многих религиях чаши (чашки) той или иной формы и объёма используются как предметы культа, например потир в христианстве или поющие чаши в восточных религиях. Их с кружками не путают.